# Listen to custom events from another custom elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling

I have two Javascript custom elements (let's call them source and destination). Source triggers a custom event that bubbles up fine
to document and I can catch it there with an event listener. If I add an event listener to a div in my destination custom element
the same event is not captured. Is that correct or should I be able to catch a custom event from another custom element?

```
elAuthorSelect.dispatchEvent(new window.CustomEvent('authorChanged', {
        detail: { name: 'test' },
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false,
        composed: true

      })
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I've misunderstood bubbling. It seems as can been read in this link https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing under the heading Capture that bubbling/capture only travel up/down it's own branch and not to other branches in the dom. I thought of dispatchevent as more of a broadcast thingy.